# How to query between alphabet range in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can i query with sequelize between an alphabet range?
Like: I want to get all registers that startsWith letters A to E.
I've been trying to get it like this but it just gets the "E" items

````
      where: {
        id: user.id,
        name: {
          [Op.and]: {
            [Op.startsWith]: 'a',
            [Op.startsWith]: 'b',
            [Op.startsWith]: 'c',
            [Op.startsWith]: 'd',
            [Op.startsWith]: 'e',
          },
        },
      },
    });```
````

Comment: Every name should `startWith` `a` __or__ `b`, not `a` __and__ `b`

Comment: Please indicate what DBMS you use